# How to solve the problem of hiding under the previous tag using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have an extension that can change the HTML of the websites. In this app, I want to add a span tag that contains an SVG tag. It works fine but there is a problem that sometimes SVG is hidden under the previous section like this picture.
[image]

Here is the code that belongs to this section.

```css
.auto-time-popup-span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.quick-popup-icon {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px -2px rgb(128 128 128 / 35%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span data-value="8 a.m. PT" class="auto-time-popup-span">
     <span style="background-color:#f5f7c6;">8 a.m. PT</span>
<svg width="30" class="quick-popup-icon"></svg>
</span>
```

Comment: Hi Hanie, this code doesn't quite match the output you have a screenshot of. Can you add the rest of the code necessary to result in the output shown in your screenshot?

Comment: @TylerH Hey! This is all of my code I just removed the path of SVG to be clear. as I said this is an extension and I've just added these lines in the HTML of other websites.

Comment: In order to reproduce this (see [mcve] for more info), we need to see the HTML of the site that is getting covered up in your screenshot. Please add that to the question, because it's not currently clear what is original and what is getting added. This context of how what you wrote vs how it interacts with something else is called "integration testing" and is an important step in testing disparate components of a website or program. You can't test integration without both pieces.

Comment: @TylerH Could You please add this extension with this like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-time-zone-converter/kfmhaonghmgncmpeggdeiigffbjecohi and after installing search oscar air time in Google.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to add **z-index** to **.auto-time-popup-span** like this:

```
.auto-time-popup-span {
z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to your CSS like this :

```
.auto-time-popup-span{
  padding-top : 5px;  /*Or according to need you can check by making changes*/
  z-index : 5;     /*Value must be 1 greater than your any z-index in code*/
}
```

Comment: You should add padding to the whole line if possible . Also complete code is not given so can try this